# MVC templates where create template and edit template need to be different?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I've found information about Editor and Detail templates based on object name (i.e. DateTime, MyCustomObject) for use with MVC system.  I am just wondering if it was possible for creating templates for use when creating the items in a similar fashion, where the form used for Creating the items is going to be different than the Editing Screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can tell MVC to distinguish between templates a few different ways.

You can tell the view what template to use.

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyCustomObject, "MyCustomObjectCreate") %>
```

vs

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyCustomObject, "MyCustomObjectEdit") %>
```

Or if you are using view models you can use Data Annotations to tell it what template to use right in the model.

So your Edit view model would look like this:

```
public class MyCustomObjectEditViewModel
{
    [UIHint("MyCustomObjectEdit")]
    MyCustomObject CustomObject { get; set; }
}
```

and your Create view model would look like this:

```
public class MyCustomObjectCreateViewModel
{
    [UIHint("MyCustomObjectCreate")]
    MyCustomObject CustomObject { get; set; }
}
```